# How to find most occurred element in each row of a multidimentional array?

Tags: python, python-2.7

suppose I have an array:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1]])
```

How can I compute another array `b` with most occurred values? ie.

```
b=([[0],[1]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `scipy` available, you could use `scipy.stats.mode`:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1]])
>>> import scipy.stats
>>> most, mostcc = scipy.stats.mode(a, axis=1)
>>> most
array([[ 0.],
       [ 1.]])
>>> mostcc
array([[ 5.],
       [ 6.]])
```

Note, from the docs:

> If there is more than one such value, only the first is returned.
>   The bin-count for the modal bins is also returned.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through each element of the array, in this case each element is [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1] and [1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1].

```
for myarr in a:
```

Loop through each element of myarr:

```
for myele in myarr
```

Use a dict to keep track of the number of occurrences:

```
mydict[myele] += 1
```

Keep track of the highest value:

```
mymost = myele if mydict[myele] > mymost
```

After finishing up with myarr, append mymost to your result:

```
mymosts.append(mymost)
```

Comment: thanks Eugene.. But the array i am working on is very big... I used this example to explain my question

Comment: How does that change the approach? Are you memory limited? Do you want an fast algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
b = [np.bincount(x).argmax() for x in a]
```

or to get the format you were showing:

```
b = ([[np.bincount(x).argmax()] for x in a])
```

If you want this to work with floats using a `Counter` would be the best standard-library solution.

```
from collections import Counter
b = ([[Counter(x).most_common()[0][0]] for x in a])
```

Comment: it worked in this case. But for a larger array it shows --TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: @user3718501 that is because `np.bincount` is for an array of non-negative ints... like the one you showed in your question.